# Combining Cython with MKL

Tags: python, c, cython

I want to use some functions of the MKL-library in my cython-code. Thus I wrote the function

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MKL__Complex16 double _Complex
#include <mkl.h>
#include <mkl_cblas.h>
#include <mkl_blas.h>
#include <mkl_lapack.h>
#include <mkl_lapacke.h>
inline void scalarMult(const double _Complex *a, const int a_len, double _Complex *b, const int b_len, const double z)
{
    if(a_len != b_len)
        return;
    if(z == 1)
        memcpy(b, a, a_len);
    else
        cblas_daxpy(a_len, (z-1), (double*)a, 1, (double*)b, 1);
}
```

(and yes, I am loosing precision, but that is not the point).
Now I looked the necessary commands up [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor), and added them to the setup.py-file in the `extra-compile-args`-part in the configuration.

```
 -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm
```

Now the compiler (gcc) first complains about the unknown commands `--start-group` and `--end-group`, and afterwards I get the error during execution:

```
./cython_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: cblas_daxpy
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Which OS? What is the gcc version?

Comment: gcc 4.8.2, Ubuntu 14.04.1